# Big O notation of looping through each character in a string before inserting into a map

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I'm new to big O notation and have a couple of questions about it in my program.

I have a program that has 2 maps. Before adding to one of the maps I loop through each character and randomly change the casing. 
I just put the string into the other map (no manipulation)

If the big O of inserting into a map is  O(1), what is it if I am looping through each character before putting it into a map?
What will be the total big O complexity of this program( combining each insertion into the maps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string of size n and you iterate over it, performing an O(1) insertion in the inner loop, then the time complexity is O(n).

To make this slightly less trivial, assume insertion costs **a** (where **a** could be a function of n, a constant, or something else entirely), then the total cost would be O(an+a).  This is because you're doing the insertion in the inner loop n times, then one additional time for the whole string.  In your case, a=1, so we have O(1n+1) = O(n).

Comment: I don't insert to the map on every loop. After the loop I add the result to the map

Comment: I misunderstood.  Then I assume you can now see that you have O(n+a) = O(n+1) = O(n).

Comment: Sry I didnt explain properly David.
So looping through string and inserting into a map = O(n) where n is the number of characters?

Comment: Yes.  The important point is that big O is all about describing how the size of the input affects the runtime of the algorithm.  Here, the input is a string with n characters.  Every character is used once, independent of the other characters, so the affect on the performance is on the order of O(n).